# Converting C++ GUID to delphi TGUID?

Tags: c++, delphi, guid

How can this be done?

I need the C++ content below to be converted to a conventional Delphi TGUID string:

`var WPD_OBJECT_SIZE = new Guid(0xEF6B490D, 0x5CD8, 0x437A, 0xAF, 0xFC, 0xDA, 0x8B, 0x60, 0xEE, 0x4A, 0x3C);`

Is there some kind of online tool for that?

The reason I need to do this is because I can not find any info about the specific `WPD_OBJECT_SIZE` GUID on [**MSDN** documentation what so ever](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff597893(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: `const WPD_OBJECT_SIZE: TGUID = (D1: $EF6B490D; D2: $5CD8; D3: $437A; D4:($AF, $FC, $DA, $8B, $60, $EE, $4A, $3C));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to using [`StringFromCLSID`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683917.aspx) or indeed any function that converts a GUID to a string. Then you have the GUID in the format that Delphi expects for its GUID literals. You'd write a C++ program, include the relevant header file, and emit the textual version of the GUID to the console.

Of course, if it's just this one GUID, that's easy. It is:

```
'{EF6B490D-5CD8-437A-AFFC-DA8B60EE4A3C}'
```